# How can I plug FileMerge into my Source Control App

Tags: xcode, permission, macos

I'd like to use FileMerge (Version 2.8) as Git and Perforce's Diff viewer, however whenever one of these apps tries to do a diff I get this message:

[image: FileMerge Error]

This isn't just for Groovy files either,it's for any type of file I try to run a diff against.  This is happening on systems running 10.9 and 10.8.

This is how I have it configured in Perforce:

[image]

Comment: The SourceControl clients are calling it directly and passing the files to FileMerge as arguments. I'll append another photo of the config to my original question.

Comment: @Mark I just posed a screenshot of my P4 config to the original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are setting an app bundle in the config when the version control program is expecing a Unix command line.

You should use /usr/bin/opendiff as the command line. I think that is the only chnage you need for the perforce diff you show.

Example git configs for merging are in this  [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22392/how-to-use-xcode-4-mergetool-in-a-standalone-fashion?rq=1) and several other duplicates on StackOverflow.